# Angular $routeProvider and Controller As Syntax

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, ngroute

Can anyone tell me if it is valid to use `$routeProvider` with `Controller as syntax`? I am having issues accessing `<h1>{{kickController.foo}}</h1>` from the controller where `this.foo` resides.

```
angular.module('ucp.kick', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, APP_BASE_URL) {
  return $routeProvider.when(APP_BASE_URL + 'kicks', {
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    navitem: true,
    name: 'Kicks',
    templateUrl: 'kick/partials/kick.html',
    controller: 'kick as KickController'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You could not add controllerAs syntax in `controller` option of
>   `$routeProvider.when`.

You should use `controllerAs` option which has been provided for taking alias of controller in string format, & `controller` also accept the string which would be considered as controller of angular.

**Code**

```
$routeProvider.when(APP_BASE_URL + 'kicks', {
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    navitem: true,
    name: 'Kicks',
    templateUrl: 'kick/partials/kick.html',
    controller: 'KickController'
    controllerAs: 'kick' //controller alias taken out from controller option
});
```

**OR**

```
controller: 'KickController as kick'
```

[**Doc Link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)